# Implement swipe functionality to my small view page

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, swipe

I'm doing a responsive web, and for smartphone version I need to implement the swipe funcionality to be able to swipe the screen with your fingers and get another section.

For example if I do a search and I'm watching the results list, I'd like to be able to swipe right and get the filter results menu.I've never done it before and I've searched in Internet and all I see is the posibility of doing something when swipe event is fired, like an alert or change the background-color, but I don't get how to implement that functionality. It would be great if I can do it with Javascript or Jquery. Any hint will be helpfull.

UPDATED

I've found this code for a basic swipe with touchSwipe Jquery plugin, but I'm not sure what I could do after a swipe callback. In the example just a text comes up. Another doubt is which element should hold the swipe event. In the example is $("#test"). But maybe I should put $("body") ?? I'm sorry for my ignorance.

```
<script id='code_1'>
  $(function() {            
    //Enable swiping...
    $("#test").swipe( {
    //Generic swipe handler for all directions
       swipe:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount, fingerData) {
         $(this).text("You swiped " + direction );  
       },
       //Default is 75px, set to 0 for demo so any distance triggers swipe
       threshold:0
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: This plugin may be of some use: https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin

Comment: Or [Hammer](http://hammerjs.github.io/). No jQuery required.

Comment: Rory I've updated the question to you see which are my doubts about it.